# C# Using a private variable inside an event handler

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling

I subscribed to an event with the following event handler. Basically, the handler receives an updated list of alarms where each alarm has a severity level. If the previous list has less high-severity alarms than the new list (i.e. new ones have been added) then I sound the alarm.

Am I using the private variable properly? Every time I get a list of alarms I process it, and then I save the number of high severity audible alarms in a private variable to be compared with the next list I receive. If the new list has more (i.e. new ones) I sound the alarm.

I believe the handler may be executed by a worker thread, right? I'm wondering if multiple threads have the correct value of the private variable `m_previousNumberOfHighSeverityAudibleAlarms`. I wrapped the handler inside a lock but is this how it should be done? I'm no expert in multithread stuff.

```
    private int m_previousNumberOfHighSeverityAudibleAlarms = 0;

    private void AlarmList_WindowDataChanged(object sender, AlsWindowDataChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (syncObj)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.WindowDataItems != null && e.TotalSize > 0)
                {
                    var previousNumberOfHighSeverityAudibleAlarms = m_previousNumberOfHighSeverityAudibleAlarms;
                    
                    currentNumberOfHighSeverityAudibleAlarms = e.WindowDataItems.Count(
                            al => Convert.ToInt32(al.Fields[8]) >= m_highSeverityAudibleRangeMinimum    // High Severity Audible Range Minimum here.
                                  && Convert.ToInt32(al.Fields[8]) <= m_highSeverityRangeMaximum);      

                          
                        if (currentNumberOfHighSeverityAudibleAlarms > previousNumberOfHighSeverityAudibleAlarms)
                        {
                            SoundManagerComponent.AlarmsMuted = false;
                            var highSeveritySoundFile = SystemConfigurationComponent.GetSubsystemSetting("gcs", "alarmmanagementservice", "HighSeveritySoundFile").SettingValue;
                            SoundManagerComponent.SetRepeatSound(highSeveritySoundFile, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), SoundManagerComponent.AlarmsVolume);
                        }
                        
                        m_previousNumberOfHighSeverityAlarms = currentNumberOfHighSeverityAlarms;
                        m_previousNumberOfHighSeverityAudibleAlarms = currentNumberOfHighSeverityAudibleAlarms;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SoundManagerComponent.StopRepeatedSound();
                        // This property is updated here because the AlarmManagementService's WindowDatChanged event is unreliable (AGUI product CR atvcm01122434)
                        m_alarmManagementService.HighPriorityUnacknowledgedAlarmsExist = false;
                        currentNumberOfHighSeverityAlarms = 0;
                        currentNumberOfHighSeverityAudibleAlarms = 0;
                                                  
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Trace.TraceError("Error while counting the number of high-severity alarms. Ex: " + ex.Message);
                }
```

Comment: The `lock` will prevent multiple threads interfering with each other with respect to that variable. It also means that that entire block of code can only be executed by one thread at a time and, if another thread wants to execute it, it will have to wait until the current thread finishes doing so. Whether that is appropriate is another matter.

Comment: Unrelated: You are doing this: `Convert.ToInt32(al.Fields[8])` twice. Why not convert once and reuse the result? Or better: If that's possible have it be an `int` in the first place?